# change css from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to change this

```
body.sidebar_b .sidemenu {
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) !important;
}
```

into this:

```
body.sidebar_b .sidemenu {
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) !important;
}
```

, but don't have access to edit neither html or css files!

**The only thing i can do is add a small javascript code inside the footer section.**

This is few examples of what i tried so far, but seems i'm going in wrong direction.

```
1#
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body.sidebar_b .sidemenu').css({
'background-color' : 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)'
});
});
</script>

2#
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var cols = document.getElementsByClassName('sidemenu');
  for(i=0; i<cols.length; i++) {
  cols[i].style.backgroundColor = 'white';
 }
 });
</script>
```

Comment: #1 script should do what you need... only use 'background-color' instead of 'background'

Comment: #1, but you need to replace the `:` with a `,`.

Comment: @krillgar, the `:` is correct. Note the curly braces

Comment: ^ given that jquery is loaded, otherwise stay away from $ or jQuery, you can simply do ```document.getElementById("Element_ID").style.backgroundColor="rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)";```

Comment: @ann0nC0d3r i have tryied with backgdound-color, but still no change.

Comment: It may be being overridden. Try placing `!important` at the end... `'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) !important'` just to see if it takes effect. This is not good practice though to just chuck `!important` at the end ;-)

Comment: @ann0nC0d3r no change. It shouldn't be overritten by something else when using $(document).ready right?

Comment: Well, by overridden, I mean the current `!important` flag will take precendant over your jQuery that is not using `!important` tag. I don't mean something else is being applied after DOM ready :)

Comment: @Cris this can be achieved with pure CSS, I would like to add a solution as well even if their is a accepted answer, Do you mind telling me if there are any CSS files referenced after your `footer` section? If yes, then does these file which come after your footer tag has the CSS rule which you want to override?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
function addNewStyle(newStyle) {
    var styleElement = document.createElement('style');
    styleElement.type = 'text/css';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(styleElement);
    styleElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(newStyle));
}

addNewStyle('body.sidebar_b .sidemenu { background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) !important;}’);
```

Comment: Something along these lines is what I would have answered.

Comment: Your solution looks interesting, but not working. I will play with it in jsfiddle to get a better understanding.

Comment: Make sure the new style tag is appended AFTER the initial one that sets the rule

Comment: Since i don't have access to any files, all i can think about is using jQuery $(document).ready(function addNewStyle(newstyle) {your code}

Comment: It worked, after finnally! seing the typo at the end. It's **' instead of ’** :p

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the CSS rule is **!important** and the rule you are adding is not.

jQuery [doesn't provide an API for setting important rules](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/2066) so you need to go down to the DOM for that.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body .sidebar_b .sidemenu').each(function() {
    console.log(this);
    this.style.setProperty("background-color", "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)", "important");
  });
});
```

```css
body .sidebar_b .sidemenu {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) !important;
  color: white;
}
body {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar_b">
  <div class="sidemenu">
    Note that the class has been moved off the body for the same of this demo
  </div>
</div>
```